# why "single-{custom-posttype}.php" not work?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
public static function bm_film_post_type(  ) {


    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'فیلم ها', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'فیلم', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'فیلم ها', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'فیلم', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'اضافه کردن', 'فیلم', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'اضافه کردن فیلم', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'فیلم جدید', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'ویرایش فیلم', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'نمایش فیلم', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'همه فیلم ها', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'جست و جوی فیلم', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'فیلم والد:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'فیلمی پیدا نشد.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'فیلمی داخل زباله دان پیدا نشد.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'film' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category' )

    );

    register_post_type( 'film', $args );
}


single page code: <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php View::render('partsial/top-menu');?>
<?php View::render('partsial/under-top-menu');?>
<?php View::render('partsial/menu-under-posts');?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

when i click more button for go to the single page , back to the index.

my single page name is single-film.php

Comment: What “more” button? Show us how that is created, and what it actually points to. (This does not sound as if it had primarily to do with whether or not the template file was found/used or not. If it wasn’t, then you should simply see your content rendered out by the default template.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please first take backup of current theme then follow the steps below.

- Active any other theme
- then active current theme again.

Hope then issue will be fixed and let me know still have any issue.

Comment: Let me know it's helpful or not

Comment: tnx , I forgot to use the loop!